# Restore MySQL sql dump by nodejs without mysqldump

Tags: mysql, node.js, dump

There is sql file. It has to be used for test cases. I need to restore it. I would like to restore it without third party utils. I've made few attempts. I receive new limitations these I can not resolve easy. An easier solution has to exist. Another solutions I have seen from networks do not satisfy requirements. I can not restore functions because of semicolons in sql text.

```
async function rawSQLFromFile(connection, path) {
  const text = fs.readFileSync(path).toString()
  const queries = text.split(';')
  for(const query of queries) {
    await runQuery(connection, query)
  }
}
```

I use [mysql library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) But it does not have the functionality.

Comment: Can you add some info about `I can not restore functions because of brackets` and `it does not have the functionality` ? It is a bit unclear what you mean by that...

Comment: And did you notice this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-import

Comment: I've corrected. It is because of semicolons. The text is divided into subqueries by semicolons. The problem is that the function definition have semicolons.

Comment: I will check the library. It looks better than I have tried before.

Comment: @Luuk I've checked the library https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-import. :) It also does not import the function. I have been looking at code. It does not process begin end constructions at all. So the library has the same issue as my code.

Comment: Can you show the sql of a function that does not import?, i just tested with [hello](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) and it gets imported without problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, although this should work with your lib:

```js
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  // described at https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#multiple-statement-queries
  multipleStatements: true,
  // your connection options follow here
});
connection.query(yourSqlFileContent, (err) => { console.log(err ? err : 'restored!') });
```

Comment: It has to work at core level according to the lines: ```// May send multiple statements per COM_QUERY and COM_STMT_PREPARE
    defaultFlags.push('+MULTI_STATEMENTS');``` But it does not ...